# info grabbing from a column with grep, awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have the following tabel:

```
^2num^5|^2score^5|^2ping^5 | ^2status ^5| ^2name players      ^5|        ^2address
---- ------- ------ -------- -------------------- -----------------------^7
^5 0 ^2|^3  41 ^2|^3 100 ^2|^5 Player ^2|^7Just a Cr4zy name!   ^2|^77.18.76.12:58641   ^3[^5FR^3]^7
^5 2 ^2|^3   3 ^2|^3  57 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot1                   ^2|^7bot
^5 3 ^2|^3   7 ^2|^3  43 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot2                   ^2|^7bot
^5 4 ^2|^3  18 ^2|^3  16 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot3                   ^2|^7bot
^5 5 ^2|^3   2 ^2|^3 103 ^2|^5 Player ^2|^7Just a ^5Cr4zy n4me2!   ^2|^784.18.8.144:27960   ^3[^5IL^3]^7
^5 6 ^2|^3  18 ^2|^3 102 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot4                   ^2|^7bot
^5 7 ^2|^3  29 ^2|^3 102 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot5                   ^2|^7bot
^5 8 ^2|^3  39 ^2|^3  54 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot                    ^2|^7bot
^5 9 ^2|^3  24 ^2|^3  77 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot                    ^2|^7bot
^510 ^2|^3  10 ^2|^3 103 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot                    ^2|^7bot
^511 ^2|^3  42 ^2|^3  95 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot                    ^2|^7bot
^512 ^2|^3   2 ^2|^3 103 ^2|^5 Player ^2|^7Ju5t a ^5Cr4zy ^7name3!      ^2|^722.185.55.9:13565   ^3[^5IL^3]^7
^513 ^2|^3  24 ^2|^3  96 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot                    ^2|^7bot
^514 ^2|^3   0 ^2|^3  51 ^2|^3  Bot   ^2|^7^8bot                    ^2|^7bot
^2-------------------------------------------------------------------------^7
^5Bots : ^311 ^5, Players : ^33 ^5, All : ^314
```

I would like to grab the info per line: num and address
Every column starts and ends with a color code i do not need. Like in column 1, it starts with ^5 and ends with ^2
The lines with a bot can also be skipped.

output i prefer:

```
0 77.18.76.12
5 84.18.8.144
12 22.185.55.9
```

Seperate i would like to have the number of players as displayed in the last line.

preferable with sed, grep or awk

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In first column there is an entry `^510 ^2`. Is this a typo and should be `^5 10 ^2` or the real data does not have a space after `^5` ?

Comment: no, is not a typo. the numbers 0-9 have a space, 10 and higher have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/) {
           print substr($0,3,2),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }
 0 77.18.76.12
 5 784.18.8.144
12 722.185.55.9
```

If there is an ip looking string in the record, `print`it and characters 3 and 4 from the beginning of the record. Naturally will fail if player uses an ip address as name.

A separate script to count the players:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/) {
           i++ }           # player counter
       END{ print "Players : " i+0 }' file
```

Comment: Woow, many thanks. it worked in the live modes.. And that if ppl have an IP as name, i can cover that by warning them and kick them out :)

Comment: Have you maybe an answer on the second question: Seperate i would like to have the number of players as displayed in the last line.?

Comment: I am sorry by not complete to be clear on this, but i need the amount of players as a separate code.

Comment: @WHHermans I'm using `i++` to count the players while processing the ips and `END{print i}` to print out the count. It takes less effort that parsing it from the last record in file. Or did I misunderstad something?

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton

Comment: @EdMorton You are right, I was trying to encourage OP to experiment with the original answer.